# PHP PDO Pagination not refreshed

Tags: php, pdo

im quite new to PHP and im trying to make a pagination, the code works! but i need to click on the button twice to make the page refreshed/change. how do i fix this?

view/main/user/userlist.php

```
<?php
      $_SESSION['pagelim'] = 10;
      $_SESSION['page'] = $_GET['halaman'];
      if ($_SESSION['page'] == '') {
          $_SESSION['pos'] = 0;
          $_SESSION['page'] = 1;
      } else {
          $_SESSION['pos'] = ($_SESSION['page']- 1) * $_SESSION['pagelim'];
      }

      $itemcount = listpetugas::getlisted();
      $pagecount = ceil(listpetugas::getlisted()/$_SESSION['pagelim']);

      for ($i=1;$i<=$pagecount;$i++)
      { ?>
          <?php
          if ($i!=$pagecount){
              echo " <ul class='pagination'><li><a href='?controller=main&action=userlist&halaman=$i' onclick='myFunction()'>$i</a></li></ul>";?>
          <?php }
          else{
              echo "$i";
          } ?>
      <?php }  ?>
```

model/userdb.php

```
    public static function listemup()
{
    if ($_SESSION['pos'] =='' && $_SESSION['pagelim'])
    {
        $pos  = 0;
        $lim = 10;
    }
    else {
        $pos = $_SESSION['pos'];
        $lim = $_SESSION['pagelim'];
    }
    $list = [];
    $db = FirstFire::StartConnection();
    $req = $db->query("SELECT * FROM randomity LIMIT $pos,$lim");
    $rowcount = $req->rowCount();
    foreach ($req->fetchAll() as $post) {
        $list[] = new listpetugas($post['name'],$post['email'],$post['adress'],$post['wow']);
    }
    return $list;
}
```

JS

```
  <script>
      function myFunction() {
          location.reload();
      }
  </script>
```

sorry for the messy code.

Comment: show your js code

Comment: i added the code to bottom of the post, it's just a reload script, the problems still occurs even without the js code

Comment: You're javascript code is just reloading the current page everytime so your 

 `$_GET['halaman']` code never has the new variables. So Try removing this js function to begin with. I know you said it still doesn't work but you should at least see the browser address bar updating with the new variables for the page which might help locate the problem easier. In fact if you view the source of your html page, is the `<ul>` generated as you would expect?

Comment: i removed the code, the browser adress did change, but the page still show the data from before until the second click. 



example : the adress is "bla?halaman=1", and then i click the page 2 button, the adress did change to "bla?halaman=2", but the page still showing the first page until i press the page2 button the second time.

and also the <ul> is fine.

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you using sessions to store this data when a variable will do? I'm wondering if there's something funny going on with the fact you are using sessions

Comment: i fairly new to PHP and what i know is session will allow me to use variable anywhere, in this case my userlist.php and userdb.php are in different file/folder, so i use session to make the variable on userlist.php usable in userdb.php

Comment: Please learn how to use prepared statements. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.